# Elasticsearch getting stopped and starting again and again

Tags: elasticsearch, heap-memory

I am running `elasticsearch` on a `4GB` instance and having a `2GB` heap size. The `elasticsearch` runs fine but after some requests it gets stopped and than starts back on its own with the following logs.

```
[2016-07-11 11:11:04,492][INFO ][discovery                ] [Ev Teel Urizen] elasticsearch/9amXiXXmTTyV_l_s3t6gnw
[2016-07-11 11:11:07,568][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Ev Teel Urizen] new_master {Ev Teel Urizen}{9amXiXXmTTyV_l_s3t6gnw}{P.P.P.P}{P.P.P.P:$300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-07-11 11:11:07,611][INFO ][http                     ] [Ev Teel Urizen] publish_address {P.P.P.P:9200}, bound_addresses {P.P.P.P:9200}
[2016-07-11 11:11:07,611][INFO ][node                     ] [Ev Teel Urizen] started
[2016-07-11 11:11:07,641][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Ev Teel Urizen] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2016-07-11 11:11:07,912][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Ev Teel Urizen] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards start$d [[user-details-index][0]] ...]).
[2016-07-11 11:13:01,482][INFO ][node                     ] [Ev Teel Urizen] stopping ...
[2016-07-11 11:13:01,503][INFO ][node                     ] [Ev Teel Urizen] stopped
[2016-07-11 11:13:01,503][INFO ][node                     ] [Ev Teel Urizen] closing ...
[2016-07-11 11:13:01,507][INFO ][node                     ] [Ev Teel Urizen] closed
```

where `P.P.P.P` is the private IP of the instance.

> **EDIT:** Logs after changing log-level to DEBUG

```
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,129][DEBUG][index.shard              ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] recovery completed from [shard_store], took [106ms]
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,129][DEBUG][cluster.action.shard     ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] sending shard started for target shard [[user-details-index][0], node[TUeznaAxQsqaFq6iDbVUVw], [P], v[149], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=j_DlCimrSoi7kff-9Ah9xw], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2016-07-11T12:46:33.774Z]]], indexUUID [tStiDr3PRWaKIKCIHk5h0A], message [after recovery from store]
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,129][DEBUG][cluster.action.shard     ] [Cameron Hodge] received shard started for target shard [[user-details-index][0], node[TUeznaAxQsqaFq6iDbVUVw], [P], v[149], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=j_DlCimrSoi7kff-9Ah9xw], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2016-07-11T12:46:33.774Z]]], indexUUID [tStiDr3PRWaKIKCIHk5h0A], message [after recovery from store]
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,130][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Cameron Hodge] processing [shard-started ([user-details-index][0], node[TUeznaAxQsqaFq6iDbVUVw], [P], v[149], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=j_DlCimrSoi7kff-9Ah9xw], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2016-07-11T12:46:33.774Z]]), reason [after recovery from store]]: execute
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,131][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Cameron Hodge] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[user-details-index][0]] ...]).
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,131][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Cameron Hodge] cluster state updated, version [4], source [shard-started ([user-details-index][0], node[TUeznaAxQsqaFq6iDbVUVw], [P], v[149], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=j_DlCimrSoi7kff-9Ah9xw], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2016-07-11T12:46:33.774Z]]), reason [after recovery from store]]
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,131][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Cameron Hodge] publishing cluster state version [4]
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,135][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Cameron Hodge] set local cluster state to version 4
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,135][DEBUG][index.shard              ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] state: [POST_RECOVERY]->[STARTED], reason [global state is [STARTED]]
[2016-07-11 12:46:34,153][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Cameron Hodge] processing [shard-started ([user-details-index][0], node[TUeznaAxQsqaFq6iDbVUVw], [P], v[149], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=j_DlCimrSoi7kff-9Ah9xw], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2016-07-11T12:46:33.774Z]]), reason [after recovery from store]]: took 23ms done applying updated cluster_state (version: 4, uuid: G_fovEaNRFOfF0lHjz0h2A)
[2016-07-11 12:47:00,583][DEBUG][indices.memory           ] [Cameron Hodge] recalculating shard indexing buffer, total is [203.1mb] with [1] active shards, each shard set to indexing=[203.1mb], translog=[64kb]
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,648][INFO ][node                     ] [Cameron Hodge] stopping ...
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,660][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closing ... (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,661][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closing index service (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,662][DEBUG][index                    ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] [0] closing... (reason: [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,664][DEBUG][index.shard              ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] state: [STARTED]->[CLOSED], reason [shutdown]
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,664][DEBUG][index.shard              ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] operations counter reached 0, will not accept any further writes
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,664][DEBUG][index.engine             ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] flushing shard on close - this might take some time to sync files to disk
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,666][DEBUG][index.engine             ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] close now acquiring writeLock
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,666][DEBUG][index.engine             ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] close acquired writeLock
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,668][DEBUG][index.translog           ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] translog closed
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,672][DEBUG][index.engine             ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] engine closed [api]
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,672][DEBUG][index.store              ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index][0] store reference count on close: 0
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,672][DEBUG][index                    ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] [0] closed (reason: [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,672][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closing index cache (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,672][DEBUG][index.cache.query.index  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] full cache clear, reason [close]
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,673][DEBUG][index.cache.bitset       ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] clearing all bitsets because [close]
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,673][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] clearing index field data (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,674][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closing analysis service (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,674][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closing mapper service (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,674][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closing index query parser service (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,680][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closing index service (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,680][DEBUG][indices                  ] [Cameron Hodge] [user-details-index] closed... (reason [shutdown])
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,680][INFO ][node                     ] [Cameron Hodge] stopped
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,680][INFO ][node                     ] [Cameron Hodge] closing ...
[2016-07-11 12:47:01,685][INFO ][node                     ] [Cameron Hodge] closed
```

Comment: First, try to change logging level to get more information about eventual problem. Go to elastic_home/config/logging.yml, open it in text editor and change es.logger.level: INFO to DEBUG.

Comment: @mdziob See the logs after changing the log-level to DEBUG